# Too old to be a lawyer?

Tags: australia, lawyer

I’m nearing 40 years old, based in Australia and I would like to steer my career towards cyber crime and litigation involving technology.

To practice law, obviously I need to do an LLB/Juris Doctor followed by PLT.  Is 40 a little late for any of this?

Comment: Is there a reason you thought it would be?

Comment: Not particularly, can eligibility/acceptance into LLB and then into a firm for PLT pose an issue due to the age factor?

Comment: You don’t necessarily need an LLB. Completing the college of Law course allows registration as a solicitor and to be a barrister you just have to pass the bar exam, no degree needed.

Comment: Thank you @DaleM , I’m unable to find the course you’re referring to on collaw.edu.au, available courses are either PLT or programs designed for individuals who are lawyers.

Comment: http://www.lpab.justice.nsw.gov.au/

Comment: Thanks again, I should’ve mentioned, Im based in VIC not sure if this is for NSW domiciles only. I’ve been working as an IT professional for about 20 years, so will have a requirement for online learning.

Comment: By online learning I mean, I’m working full time so wont be able to attend school in person. It will have to be distance learning sort of an arrangement.

Answer (score 3):

**Too old to be a lawyer?**

Legally: No.

See Part 4 of the Age Discrimination Act 2004 which...

> ...makes it unlawful to discriminate against someone on the ground of
> age in respect of the following:
>
> (a) employment and related matters;
>
> (b) education;

https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2020C00283